# Node.js Telegram API Error: 400 MEDIA_INVALID in messages.SendMultiMedia

Tags: node.js, telegram

I'm encountering an error in my Node.js application while using the telegram library (gramjs) to interact with the Telegram API. The error message I'm getting is:

```js
RPCError: 400: MEDIA_INVALID (caused by messages.SendMultiMedia)
at RPCMessageToError (/home/***/node_modules/telegram/errors/index.js:28:12)
at MTProtoSender._handleRPCResult (/home/***/node_modules/telegram/network/MTProtoSender.js:534:58)
...
```

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```js
const {Api, TelegramClient} = require("telegram");
const {getSession} = require("../sessions/sessionManager");
const config = require("../config/config");
const {CustomFile} = require("telegram/client/uploads");
const {statSync} = require("fs");
const moment = require('moment');


const session = getSession();
const client = new TelegramClient(session, config.apiId, config.apiHash, {
    connectionRetries: 5,
    proxy: {
        ip: config.proxyHost,
        port: config.proxyPort,
        MTProxy: config.proxyMtproto,
        secret: config.proxySecret,
        socksType: 5,
        // timeout: 10,
    },
});

const test = async (req, res) => {
    await client.connect(); 

    const toUpload = new CustomFile("photo.jpg", statSync("./1700.jpg").size, "./1700.jpg");
    const file = await client.uploadFile({
        file: toUpload,
        workers: 1,
    });
    const media = new Api.InputMediaUploadedPhoto({
        file: file,
    })
    const timeSchedule = moment().add(1, 'hour').unix();
    const request = new Api.messages.SendMultiMedia({
        peer: "test",
        multiMedia: [new Api.InputSingleMedia({
            media: media,
            message: 'test',
        })],
        scheduleDate: timeSchedule
    })
    console.log(request)
    const result = await client.invoke(request)

    console.log(result);

};

module.exports = {
    test: test
};
```

I'm attempting to send multiple media files with scheduled sending using messages.SendMultiMedia, but I'm receiving a MEDIA_INVALID error with an HTTP status code of 400. I've already checked the media files, their formats, and my authentication, but I'm still encountering this issue.

Also i saw [this link](https://gram.js.org/tl/messages/SendMultiMedia#messagessendmultimedia) for implementation my code

Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can resolve it? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Your "Validation error" is usually a sign that Sequelize, the ORM you are using, is having trouble validating a record before it can be saved to the database. The data you are attempting to insert does not adhere to the validation standards set for Check Sequelize Model Validation:

Go to the model file (where you define your "User" model in Sequelize).
Check the validation rules defined in the Sequelize model using Sequelize's validation decorators like notEmpty, isEmail, and others.
Ensure that the Sequelize model's validation rules match the validation rules in your DTO (UserDto) and vice versa.

**Ensure DTO Validation Is Consistent:**

Verify that the validation rules in your DTO (UserDto) are correctly defined and match the validation rules you want to apply to the user data.

**Check the Request Data:**

Ensure that the data you are trying to insert into the database matches the validation criteria specified in both the DTO and the Sequelize model.

**Error Handling:**

Implement error handling in your service to catch validation errors from Sequelize and provide meaningful error messages or responses to the client.

**Logging:**

Consider adding logging statements to help you debug and identify which validation rule is failing.th by your model, which results in this error.
You are validating your DTO (UserDto) in your code using the class-validator package. Although Sequelize also has its own validation guidelines, it's probable that the validation restrictions specified in your Sequelize model are the reason Sequelize is rejecting the data.
To fix this problem, make sure the DTO validation and Sequelize model validation rules are configured correctly and consistently.
The following methods will assist you in troubleshooting and resolving -